# Image and text alignment in WebView

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have a `WebView` with a few text and images. Here's how it looks right now:

[image]

The portion `(w-2)/2` comes from an image source, while the portion `-10` comes directly as a text. All I'm trying is to keep the text at the center (rather than bottom) after the image source, so that it looks more logical.

Is there a way I could achieve it?

Comment: You have to use some HTML/CSS for that.

Comment: how does it seem in browser ?

Comment: Try the CSS attribute `line-height:<height of the image>`. For example, if the image is 32px, the CSS would be `line-height:32px`. If you show your HTML, it would help more.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna,  It must be the same in browser as it's in `WebView`.

Comment: @user5038993 that means it is well seen even from the mobile browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some CSS rules like `vertical-align` or maybe `float: left;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp